# Failure INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES

Tags: android, flutter

i'm getting this error when i want to install my flutter app in my phone(Xiaomi Redmi Note 9T).

#### I tried to run new flutter template project (Counter App) and i'm still getting this error.

my app install and run on emulator and works fine.

my phone developer options and USB debugging is enabled.

##### i'm using:

flutter 2.10.0

Dart 2.16.0

ubuntu 20.04.3

Android Studio Bumblebee 2021.1.1 Patch 1

#### Error

```
Error: ADB exited with exit code 1
Performing Streamed Install

adb: failed to install /home/*****/Documents/Projects/*****/build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app.apk: Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES: Failed collecting certificates for /data/app/vmdl1511670516.tmp/base.apk: Failed to collect certificates from /data/app/vmdl1511670516.tmp/base.apk using APK Signature Scheme v2: SHA-256 digest of contents did not verify]
Error launching application on M2007J22G.
```

this is my **gradle** file.

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 31 //flutter.compileSdkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "*******"
        minSdkVersion 21 //flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi, have you tried to turn off MIUI optimization under your developer options in your phone?

Comment: yes, it's not working.

Comment: Disabling MIUI optimization worked :D